# Публикация комментария после проверки

Tags: html, javascript, html5, php

Как сделать так, чтоб люди могли оставлять комментарии у меня на сайте, но только после проверки?

Хочу сделать так, чтоб люди могли зайдя на сайт, оставить комментарий, но перед этим они должны представится и указать, хотят ли они следить за продолжением комментариев, и ввести код, для подтверждения того, что это человек. После этого комментарий должен прийти ко мне джя редактирования.

Как мне это сделать, может есть какие программы по созданию комментариев? Ну или с помощью какого языка можно всё это создать?

Comment: >"Ну или с помощью какого языка можно всё это создать?" 

C помощью тех, что в тегах.

>"может есть какие программы по созданию комментариев?"
:D:D:D

Comment: рограммы по созданию комментариев эта 12 :D

Comment: "может есть какие программы по созданию комментариев?"

=D эта штука называется "руки"

Comment: *Ещё одна смешная шутка про программу для создания комментариев*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала изучи простейший скрипт регистрации php + MySQL для того чтобы люди могли "представиться", написать комментарий, прописать проверку на спам, а после ты смог его редактировать. SMTP сервер, чтобы человек мог отследить комментарии. Вот [тут](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=369) есть большая часть скрипта и пояснения к нему, чтоб хотяб понять, что требуется. Да и еще, чтоб все это можно было легко просматривать установи локальный сервер, инструкция [тут](http://ab-w.net/PHP/server_set.php). Также найди Adobe Dreamweawer, хоть многие считают что лучше блокнот, но мне с ним было как-то комфортнее.

Comment: Наверное, человеку будет гораздо легче использовать xammp для работы с локальным сервером?